# Как воспроизвести музыку в C++?

Tags: c++, linux, аудио

Как программно воспроизвести звук в C++?

Я конечно много нагуглил вариантов, но вот незадача. Мне нужно несколько вещей от библиотеки:

1.Поддержка в Linux (само собой)

2.Не требовать обращения к `/dev/snd` (чтобы мне, как разработчику, не приходилось прописывать это обращение явно)

3.Поддерживать ЛЮБЫЕ форматы (MP3, OGG, WAV, FLAC, M4A, OPUS).

4.Статическая линковка

Единственное, что лично я нашёл - libao. Простой документированный код, и всем условиям удовлетворяет, кроме одного: не линкуется статически. Вообще. Нету статической версии...

Не знаю, вроде бы ещё SDL есть, но я хз, как его код писать, соберется ли он статически, и где бы к нему документацию по части аудио взять. Плюс, мне надо, чтобы он работал строго из консоли, как mpv или sox, не требуя графики (мб разве что ncurses...)

И да, язык строго-настрого C++ (ну или C соответственно). ОС - Linux, Windows/BSD/macOS-специфичные либы не предлагать!

Comment: ffmpeg с его ffplay?

Answer (score 0):

В линуксе многие кодеки линкуются только динамикой из-за патентных проблем  и даже если линканешь статикой фреймворк, то он все равно будет делать dlopen.

Третий пункт и четвертый вместе не выполнимы.

Не мучай себя - возьми libav или gstreamer - они есть на всех десктопах.

Comment: dlopen не проблема: `gcc -o main main.c -static -ldl`. Сам часто собираю свои или пересобираю существующие проги статически, я знаю нюансы